# GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wing/Missile%20Wing 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel

```
<a href="{{ url('wing/Missile Wing') }}">Missile Wing</a>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/wing/{wing}', [UserController::class, 'wing']);
```

i need to pass the Missile Wing Parameter through route to Controller.but route doesn't call.

Comment: have you tried `url('wing/Missile%20Wing')` or any other valid url option like `url('wing/missile-wing')` or `url('wing?wing=Missile%20Wing')`

Comment: I tried 'url('wing/Missile%20Wing')'

Comment: You need to show the wing action implementation i think you have error over there.

Comment: If you remove the space, can you get it to work? If not, something general is amiss that's not in your Q above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Named route: `wing`**

Try modifying your html to include a named route:

```
<a href="{{ route('wing', ['wing' => 'Missile Wing']) }}">Missile Wing</a>
```

The array above is assigning the value `"Missile Wing"` to the parameter `wing` on the route.

Then modify your route to include `->name('wing')` which will allow you to call the route by name.

```
Route::get('wing/{wing}', [UserController::class, 'wing'])->name('wing');
```

In your controller set the parameter of your action method to be `$wing` and print it to see if the value is `"Missile Wing"`

```
class UserController {
    public function wing(string $wing) {
        dd($wing);
    }
}
```

**Alternatively:**

if you want to pass a get parameter you can grab it in the controller via `$request->get('wing')` and you can check its presence by using `if($request->has('wing'))`

```
<a href="/wing?wing=Missile Wing">Missile Wing</a>

Route::get('wing', [UserController::class, 'wing'])

class UserController {
    public function wing(Request $request) {
        dd($request->get('wing'));
    }
}
```